# Flask passing the value from a clicked button

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

I am currently using Flask and python. I have the following code for the html file:

```
<body>
  {% for result in rest_info %}
  <div class="cotainer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="{{result2}}">{{result[2]}}</button>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </body>
```

I would like to transition to a different html based on the button clicked. I wrote jQuery script something like this to get the value of the button pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
       var stored_value = $(this).id;
   });
});
```

I am wondering how I can pass stored_value to a view function in Flask python... Thanks for your help!
 EDIT: the list of buttons is arbitrarily long!

Answer (score 0):

To get something from the browser to a view function, you're going to need to make a request. There are lots of ways to make this happen, like clicking an `<a>` tag, submitting a `<form>`, or having jQuery do `location = '?value=2';`.

You can probably solve this problem without JavaScript. Consider the following template:

```
{% if request.args.blah != '1' %}
<a href="/?blah=1">Result</a>
<p>The regular HTML</p>
{% else %}
<a href="/">Result</a>
<p>This HTML is different!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. Could you help me understand how to use request.args.whateverror? I understand how to use request.form, but I looked at documentation for args and still confused..

Comment: When a URL ends with `?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3`, that's called the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). `request.args`, in that case, is basically a dictionary that looks like `{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"}`.  In Jinja2 (the template system that Flask uses), `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo['bar']` if `foo` is a dictionary.